# jQuery validation: errors are not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I added jQuery Validation to my code, and the custom messages for each field are not displayed. I just get a red box on the validated fields and a default popup: "This is a required field".

Please take a look at the code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    lastname: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Enter your first name",

                    lastname: "Enter your last name",

                    email: "Enter your email",

                    message: "Enter the message"

                },
            });
        });


    </script>


<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="firstname">First name: </label>  
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="lastname">Last name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why you have added multiple references of `jquery` and `jquery-validate`? Try again after fixing this.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the multiple references of jquery, but I get the same result :(

Comment: The "default popups" you describe sounds like HTML5 validation as per the browser, since this plugin has nothing to do with popups.  You have not properly included the jQuery files.

Comment: Is the jQuery validate file actually located here at the path you've specified?  `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inclusion of js files was an issue. Also, make sure you have a proper reference to validate.js.

```css
.mr15{
  margin-right:15px;
}

label.error{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    lastname: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Enter your first name",

                    lastname: "Enter your last name",

                    email: "Enter your email",

                    message: "Enter the message"

                },
            });
        });


    </script>


<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="firstname">First name: </label>  
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="mr15" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="lastname">Last name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="mr15" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email" >Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="mr15" required /> <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="message">Message: </label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="mr15" required ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I run code snippet I see the custom messages here, but in my app the custom messages are not displayed even after adding the suggested code :(

Comment: @AMY If the error messages are not displayed it could be the issue with the validator. do you see any console errors?

Comment: Yes, I see the following error when running the code in IE.

Comment: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

Comment: @AMY, if that's the error, then you have to go back to the very start and learn how to properly include your JavaScript jQuery files onto your page.  The error means you have you not included the plugin.

Comment: @Sparky, thanks for your help. I reviewed this link https://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/, and I found the solution by adding the jQuery bundle to the top of the layout file, and now the custom errors are displayed :)